# TextView with anchor and raw links (SpannableString issue)

Tags: android, spannablestring

In my textview, I want both anchors and raw links to be clickable. I'm letting TextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL) handle all of the raw links and then retrieving the spans and setting them with SpannableString for all of the anchors.

I would like to be able to 'linkify' the anchors in my custom TextView implementation (extends TextView) in the setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) call. Everything seems to be working properly except for the setSpan() call (end, start, and span are all correct). At the end of setText(...), I'm assigning the global CharSequence var to the new SpannableString. When setText() is called from my adapter, the spans identified in Object[]spans are not linked.

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(text.toString().replace("\n", "<br />"));
    Object[] spans = html.getSpans(0, html.length(), URLSpan.class);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(html);
    for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        URLSpan span = (URLSpan) spans[i];
        int end = html.getSpanEnd(span);
        int start = html.getSpanStart(span);
        int flags = html.getSpanFlags(span);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "span: " + span.getURL() + "\nstart: " + start + "\nend: " + end);
        s.setSpan(span, start, end, flags);
    }
    mText = s;
}
```

I found a slight workaround to this issue in the code listed below. In this implementation, I'm setting the spans in the adapter instead of the CustomTextView. This method works fine but doesn't entirely fit my needs because my TextView is used as an ExpandableTextView, meaning that there are 2 sets of texts (trimmed and full) and often times the trimmed version is returned (which is fine in typical scenarios, except that I want to add tags to the full text). This implementation often crashes because the spans that were originally identified were for the fullText and getText() is returning the trimmedText. So I think it'll be necessary for me to be able to do this in my custom TextView's setText(). BUT, the below method does work granted that trimmedText and fullText are the same length.

```
 Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(postText.replace("\n", "<br />"));
 Object[] spans = html.getSpans(0, html.length(), URLSpan.class);
 h.content.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
 h.content.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
 h.content.setText(html);
 h.content.setLinkTextColor(Color.rgb(136, 194, 226));
 h.content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Need this otherwise the view disappears....

 SpannableString ss = (SpannableString) h.content.getText();
 for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
      URLSpan span = (URLSpan) spans[i];
      int end = html.getSpanEnd(span);
      int start = html.getSpanStart(span);
      int flags = html.getSpanFlags(span);
      ss.setSpan(span, start, end, flags);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved my problem:

At the point of my problem, I had already parsed through the content and added anchors (HTML links that would launch an activity when clicked) to my tags (@ and #). I also wanted to make raw (e.g., www.google.com) clickable, so I tried setting my TextView to setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL) but this broke the anchor links.

So this is what I did:

```
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = 
            new SpannableStringBuilder(Html.fromHtml
                    (this.content.replace("\n", "<br />")));
    Pattern urlPattern = android.util.Patterns.WEB_URL;
    Linkify.addLinks(ssb, urlPattern, "youractivityhere://");
    myTextView.setText(ssb);
```

Basically I'm using a regex matcher to find any URLs within the String and then add a link using Linkify.addLinks(...).

I was making the problem way more difficult than needed.